# Detect changes in a property after the value is changed

Tags: qt, qml

I'm currently working in a project with Qt QML and I have a type that has a property (holds a JavaScript Object), and its reference changes constantly.

What I want to do is to detect the changes in this property and compare with a cached one.

I took a look into [Qt Property Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#using-keyword-this-keyword-with-property-binding), but the callback function is executed before the change occurs and the property gets the value of the return of the callback. I want something to be executed after that (the property change), because I need to have the property `dataset` updated before emitting the signals (in the code the signals are emitted with kind of reflection thing, in the `forEach` callback).

What I've done so far:

```
Item {
    id: root

    property var dataset

    Component.onCompleted: {
        dataset = Qt.binding(function(){
            return MediaWatcherHelper.formatDataset(internals.metadata);

            // I want this code to execute after the binding occurs, but I obviously can't execute things after the return.
            MediaWatcherHelper.detectChanges(root.dataset, internals.cache)
                .forEach(it => root[`${it}Change`](dataset[it]));

            internals.cache = root.dataset; // And update the cache
        });
    }

    signal trackIdChange(string trackId)
    signal albumChange(string album)
    signal artistChange(var artist)
    signal titleChange(string title)
    signal urlChange(url url)
}
```

Comment: A common property changing notification fired *after* the property has changed. From the docs: _A signal is a notification from an object that ... a property has changed_.  A custom signal is it's entirely up to you, you decide when to fire it.

Comment: I was avoiding signals, because in signals, as far as I know we can't access past values after the signal happens. But I think its actually the correct way to solve my problem, so I made with signals.

... but still open to new ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can keep the previous value and update it accordingly.

```
property int myCurrentValue: 10
property int myLastValue: myCurrentValue

onMyCurrentValueChanged: {
    console.log("current: " + myCurrentValue + ", last:" + myLastValue)
    myLastValue = myCurrentValue;
}
```

Comment: Do we have "onMyCurrentValueChanged" natively or I need to implement it with a Signal?

Comment: Sure, all the properties have suitable handlers, from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html): _Declaring a custom property implicitly creates a value-change signal for that property, as well as an associated signal handler called on<PropertyName>Changed, where <PropertyName> is the name of the property, with the first letter capitalized._ When you define your own property in C++ class you have to create a appropriate signal using [NOTIFY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) notification.